# Check Connection still calls Error after it moved to another page(class)

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I am trying to add in the function of checking the internet connection when the user click login and stop checking if connection is found. At the moment, when there is no internet connection, everything works ok, and when there are connections it works ok as well, but when i login with connection(after it logged in into homepage), i switch off internet, the code that checks connection still execute, and i already set the interval to 1 second, not sure why it does that. 
Thanks for your time!

Code:

```
var monitor:URLMonitor = new URLMonitor(new URLRequest("http://www.google.com"));
monitor.pollInterval = 10;
monitor.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, checkHTTP);
monitor.start();

function checkHTTP(e:StatusEvent) {
    if (monitor.available) {
        trace("Internet is available");
    } else {
        removeChild(loader);
        loader = null;
        loader = new Loader();

        addChild(Bolder);
        Bolder.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ValidateAndback);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm I just realized that the title is totally not ok with the content you've provided - at least post it or explain what's the main problem - you don't want the monitor to continue work, or you don't want the error that you haven't provided?

Comment: Hi i am not sure what do you mean, you mean my title? I am not sure how to phrase it, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you want to, you can call `monitor.stop();` after you've logged in, so that it won't continue to check for the connection. So even if it's lost, nothing will happen as you're already logged in.

You can also set a variable for your current state that manages if you need connection check or not.